# mouse over and ajax tooltip

Tags: ajax, jquery, tooltip

I have a number of links which I would like to get some information by using ajax calls and display the information as tooltip.

I have bind the function that make the ajax call with the event on mouseover of the link 
something like:

```
$('#div a').bind('mouseover', function () {
   //sending the ajax call
}
```

everything looks/work fine except, when the user unintentionally move the mouse pointer over all the links, I saw that there are many ajax calls.

so my question how can I prevent the ajax call unless the users hover the mouse pointer on the link for at least 3 or 4 seconds first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up the JavaScript `window.setTimeout()` function.

Comment: Let's say we have something like this:
`window.setTimeout(ajaxFunction,4000);` then it's not ganna work:

after 4second, first ajax calls

after 8 seconds, 2nd ajax calls

after 12seconds, 3rd ajax calls

Comment: May I ask why you can't load the tooltips along with the page?